# Anaconda-navigator and spyder are not opening after install the latest version of Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

i tried the command `conda update --all` and it does not work. Any Advice or solution for this problem?

Windows 10
Python 3.7.1

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it does not work"? Can you provide us with the output of the update command and your expected result?

Comment: Please do not paste and image here, but copy your output and insert it here as code (intented with for spaces).

Comment: I mean anaconda-navigator and spyder are not opening. 

I dont know how to insert the output of Anaconda prompt as code. Im beginner in this issue. im searching here how to do this.

Comment: Here is the output:

(base) C:\Users\Linican>conda update --all
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: \
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - defaults::nbconvert-5.3.1-py37_0, defaults::pandoc-2.2.3.2-0
  - defaults::nbconvert-5.4.1-py37_0, defaults::pandoc-1.19.2.1-hb2460c7done

Comment: This seems to be a common problem, there are multiple issues on github for this. Try `conda update conda` first

Comment: Did not work this command.

Comment: I cannot help you any further at this point. I suggest you search for `possible package resolutions` in GitHub issues related to conda